# HttpClients.createDefault() throws an "org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: INSTANCE" exception

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpcomponents

I'm trying to issue a POST request from my java code into a separate instance of my app.
For that purpose I included org.apache.httpcomponents library into my project and here's how I'm trying to use it:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://" + url);

List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<>();
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Constants.FILE_CONTENTS, file.getContents()));

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
post.addHeader(Constants.VERSION, Configuration.getVersion());
post.addHeader(Constants.USERID, NO_USERID);
post.addHeader(Constants.PASSWORD, NO_USERID);

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
//CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
System.out.println("Result: " + EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
```

Both "HttpClients.createDefault()" & "HttpClientBuilder.create().build()" calls throw the same exception to me and I'm not sure why.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: INSTANCE
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:108)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:323)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:206)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:218)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:161)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:114)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:184)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:107)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:163)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.crunchtime.webapp.filter.WebFilterWrapper.doFilter(WebFilterWrapper.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.crunchtime.webapp.filter.CurrentThreadFilter.doFilterInternal(CurrentThreadFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.crunchtime.webapp.filter.SiteCheckFilter.doFilter(SiteCheckFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.crunchtime.webapp.filter.PreRequestSettingsFilter.doFilterInternal(PreRequestSettingsFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:40002)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: INSTANCE
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:155)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:164)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:91)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    ... 51 more
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the order in which you initialize the object makes a difference.
I end up using this approach:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy()).build();
URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(url);

List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<>();
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(Constants.LOCATION, location));
uriBuilder.addParameters(urlParameters);

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uriBuilder.build());
httpPost.addHeader(Constants.VERSION, Configuration.getVersion());
httpPost.addHeader(Constants.USERID, NO_USERID);
httpPost.addHeader(Constants.PASSWORD, NO_USERID);

HttpEntity fileEntity = new StringEntity(file.getFile(), "UTF-8");
httpPost.setEntity(fileContentsEntity);

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
String response = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
```